How to add a local whl file to venv.zip and let everyone can use my virtual environment setting
Now I have a requirement.in to setup a virtual environment.
I want to add my loacl whl file to this vittual envionment.
But I found that when I install my.whl and used pip freeze to list all the dependency, my.whl will point to my local install path.
So if I use pip_parse, it will show some dependency error.
Do you have any idea about this situation?
I want when someone using the venv.zip with successfully using pip-parse requirements.txt
